# Angular Nested states not working as expected

Tags: angularjs, nested, state, angular-ui-router

Can someone see why this is not working? `/series` is not loading the Gallery, however the `/series/:id/seasons` part is working. (Its not a missing ng-view problem see working code below!)

```
angular.module('xbmcremoteApp')
  .config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('series', {
        url: '/series',
        templateUrl: 'app/series/series.html',
        controller: 'SeriesCtrl'
      }).state('series.gallery', {
        url: '',
        templateUrl: 'app/series/series-gallery/series-gallery.html',
        controller: 'SeriesGalleryCtrl'
      }).state('series.seasons', {
        url: '/:id/seasons',
        templateUrl: 'app/series/seasons/seasons.html',
        controller: 'SeasonsCtrl'
      });
  });
```

if i change it to this it works but thats not what i want:

```
angular.module('xbmcremoteApp')
  .config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('series', {
        url: '',
        templateUrl: 'app/series/series.html',
        controller: 'SeriesCtrl'
      }).state('series.gallery', {
        url: '/series',
        templateUrl: 'app/series/series-gallery/series-gallery.html',
        controller: 'SeriesGalleryCtrl'
      }).state('series.seasons', {
        url: '/series/:id/seasons',
        templateUrl: 'app/series/seasons/seasons.html',
        controller: 'SeasonsCtrl'
      });
  });
```

**EDIT and soltuion:**
My post lacked some information. To make that clear: 
I want to display a gallery when the `/series`url is called. And i want to display the seasons with the seasons url. No more views!
Found an very easy solution. Setting the abstract property to true forces the stateprovider to use the child view.

```
....
.state('series', {
    abstract:true,  //adding this line makes the states work as expected
    url: '/series',
    templateUrl: 'app/series/series.html',
    controller: 'SeriesCtrl'
  })
....
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first definition the url `/series` is evaluated as a root state `'series'`

```
.state('series', {
    url: '/series',          // url evaluation will stop here, because
    ...                      // there is a match for /series
  }).state('series.gallery', { // this will never be reached via url
    url: '',                   // but ui-sref="series.gallery" will work
    ...
```

While the second mapping does distinguish both states, and '/series' will navigate to `'series.gallery'` state :

```
.state('series', {
    url: '',                   // url like "#" will navigate there
    ...
  }).state('series.gallery', { // url /series will trigger this child state
    url: '/series',
    ...
```

In general, if states should be unique by url, each of them should have some defintion. So mostlikely this should be working as inteded:

```
.state('series', {
    url: '/',                   // url like "#/" will navigate to series
    ...
  }).state('series.gallery', { // url '/series' will trigger this
    url: '^/series',
    ...
```

check the magical sign: **`^`**:

- [Absolute Routes (^)](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#absolute-routes-) *(cite:)*

> If you want to have absolute url matching, then you need to prefix your url string with a special symbol `'^'`.

Comment: but why does /series/:id/season work in both definitions? even if the root state has the /series url! How does your proposal with the `^`differ from my second solution?

Comment: My suggestion (just suggestion) is just to show you, that series can have url `'/'` and series.gallery would have `'/series'`, while in your second mapping would 'series' have nothing: `''`. The 'series.seasons' is in fact **child of 'series'**, so the same principles are applied. If parent is '' and seasons are '/series/:id/season' then combination of it is `'' + '/series/:id/season'`. In your first mapping that concat has the same result `'/series/' + ':id/season'`. It is really very simple principle... nothing comples. Does ithelp?

Comment: Okay i see what you meant but in my case that would not work, i think. However i may have to think about my "child" concept. Why i did order the states like this was because the parent provides a template that applies for every url starting with `/series` and just includes specific views inside that template. I do not know how to solve that in an other way. I updated my post btw. because I found a solution working for me at the moment. Thank you :)

Comment: Hmmm, marking state as abstract means, that state is not accessible directly, only its children. So I would doubt that you've found solution. Maybe you should recheck my answer. All child states, do inherit parent url. only if there is `^`, url starts from the root. This sould be solution I'd say ;) But glad that you made it..

Comment: oh sorry... thats exactly what i wanted to achieve. I didn't state that because having parent with `/series` and child with empty url meant that i only want the child to be accessible. To make that clear I want to display a gallery when the `/series`url is called. And i want to display the seasons. No more views!